# Installing Hyper-V on SBS 2008

Tags: hyper-v, windows-sbs-2008

I'm trying to configure Hyper-V on SBS 2008. I've seen before and people have done it several times. However, I've had no success.

Actually I tried different ways to install Hyper-V so I think my current config is not that clean. Could you tell me exactly what are your network settings?

I understand you install the server with NIC1 only, then add NIC2 and install Hyper-V. A virtual NIC is added.

So what's the situation at that point? NIC1 is the main NIC. NIC2 has a static/dynamic IP address? VM NIC has a static/dynamic IP address?

Which one should be disabled? NIC2 or VM NIC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first (and very proper) reaction is, "DUDE...DON'T DO IT"

This is not a supported scenario and there is a reason for that. DHCP will break (not may break...will break). Hyper V is supposed to be on a server with no additional roles. SBS has a googol of roles installed (Active Directory, DNS, FSRM, Exchange, Sharepoint, WSUS, etc.). Hyper V should have a NIC dedicated to management with separate NICs being used for VMs. SBS 2008 only supports 1 NIC. There's a strong likelyhood that a future update will hose your system and Microsoft will simply inform you that you're running an unsupported setup. I've seen cases where an SBS server with Hyper V gets stuck on "Configuring updates" for hours and hours and hours. My point here: Hyper V on SBS is bad news!

If you'd like to do this right, it's not difficult. Install Hyper V Server (which is FREE) or Windows Server 2008 Standard with the Hyper V role (and ONLY the Hyper V role) on the bare metal. You may then setup a virtual machine with SBS 2008. There are ways of doing P2V migrations to avoid having to reinstall your system. This is the proper way of doing things and it works great. It is also an officially supported scenario (Microsoft gives it the green lights).

Here's some links of interest:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2009/08/07/you-cannot-install-the-hyper-v-role-on-the-sbs-2008-primary-server.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239207%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I finally managed to install Hyper-V on my SBS 2008... Looks OK for now, but running since a few days only. I disabled automatic updates on the host, and will have to remember to temporarly disable the 2 additional NICS before updating the server.
But you're correct. A recommended way to use hyper-v would be to install hyper-v server intead of using hyper-v role. We'll do this asap (but of course converting the sbs2008 to a VM is not simple as that).

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V is installed as a role, there is no other proper way to install it.

In the Hyper-V management console you can configure Virtual Networks. When you create an External Virtual Network you must assign a NIC to is (or a NIC Team). This NIC become a pass-through to Hyper-V's virtual switch. If you want, the host can get a Virtual NIC on this virtual switch just like a VM would.

If you suspect you're setup is 'not that clean' you should probably start over from scratch to make sure it's done right. Please (for the love of $deity) read [Microsoft's Hyper-V Planning and Deployment Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/5/81556693-1f05-494a-8d45-cdeeb6d735e0/HyperV_Deploy.doc) or find someone know really knows what they're doing.

Comment: Finally go it working. I installed a second physical NIC. Then selected this NIC when adding hyper-v role. Result is that there is a third (virtual) NIC created. The physical NIC should only have  'microsoft virtual network switch protocol' checked in his properties. The new virtual NIC should be configured as a 'standard' NIC, so with a valid IP address (same subnet as the main physical NIC), gateway and DNS (sbs main IP server's address).
Don't forget to check the advanced settings in network connections control panel, and put the main NIC in first place in 'adpaters and bindings' panel.